# docker commands do not respond

Tags: docker, docker-compose

All docker commands do not respond, even `docker logs`, `docker info` or `docker version`

`#: sudo systemctl stop docker` doesn't respond as well

`#: sudo systemctl status docker` respond with:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Thu 2020-12-17 19:12:16 MSK; 27min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 7613 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 22
     Memory: 44.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─7613 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
level=info msg="Container b25db26d185ef0b90061996d61cd169b820b0731d6b68a8c8c356b87293c810a failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
level=info msg="Container ff7095aa0124b7a4afdc2036f89c4bf51e2ccd56c3430f74690aaf21e40fcbe3 failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
```

I've run several containers through `docker-compose` before it happened. A couple of Postgres images and a couple of golang services were built statically and packed in Alpine image.

`kill -9 7613` kills dockerd but it starts anyway.

Any assumptions?

Comment: I am having the same issue. were you able to find the root cause and fix? TIA

Comment: No, I wasn't. I just disabled autoloading of dockerd with by supervisor and removed all images after restarting.